# Setting regex in python for a complex string

Tags: python, regex

I have string of ingredients of a product like this:

```
text = 'Pork and beef, water, salt (1,7%), spices (white pepper, nutmeg, coriander, cardamom), stabilizer (E450), glucose, antioxidant (E316), a preservative (E250), flavorings'
```

I want to detect all the text (ingredients) from it such that it should look like this.

```
ingredientsList= ['Pork and beef', 'salt', 'spices', 'white pepper', 'nutmeg', 'coriander', 'cardamom', 'stabilizer', 'glucose', 'antioxidant', 'preservative', 'flavorings']
```

The current regex I am using here is the following:

```
ingredients = re.findall(r'\([^()]*\)|([^\W\d]+(?:\s+[^\W\d]+)*)', text)
```

But it is not providing the the text in the bracket. I just did not want to include codes and percentages but want all the ingredients inside the brackets. What should I do here ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You may restrict the first branch to only match codes that start with `E` and are followed with number:

```
\(E\d+\)|([^\W\d]+(?:\s+[^\W\d]+)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kJpYfm/1)

Now, `\(E\d+\)` will match `(Exxx)`-like substrings only, and others will be processed. You may add the percentages here, too, to explicitly skip them - [`\((?:E\d+|\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?%)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/kJpYfm/2).

[Python demo](http://ideone.com/PkNXOd):

```
import re
rx = r"\(E\d+\)|([^\W\d]+(?:\s+[^\W\d]+)*)"
s = "Pork and beef, water, salt (1,7%), spices (white pepper, nutmeg, coriander, cardamom), stabilizer (E450), glucose, antioxidant (E316), a preservative (E250), flavorings"
res = [x for x in re.findall(rx, s) if x]
print(res)
```